# launch ruby and grunt in one command prompt

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, compass-sass

Im trynig to launch a grunt tasks in my project, one of them is compass. I'm starting Command prompt with Ruby. When typing grunt I have a mesage that it  is not recognized, but my grunt is installed, when I type `where grunt` I have confirmation that `npm/grunt` and `npm/grunt.cmd` was found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `system 'grunt'`.

Comment: We need to see an example of your command-line, and a short, summarized, version of your code that demonstrates the problem. Odds are good you're running into a problem with your child-process' environment, but we can't tell without your code.